# iphone 6 can't login to itunes and appstore?

Tags: login, iphone, itunes-store

When i type my email and password and then click to login button, After a few seconds without having to happen return to first state . what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset device and run it again. It is very encouraged to reset any device manually after upgrade to latest iOS.

To reset device kepp off button along with home button at least 10 second unless Apple logo appears.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no beneficial change